# How to upload .flr .mp3 .jpg files from firebase storage with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app is close to reaching the 150mb limit for the Playstore. I have .jpg .mp3 and .flr files taking up space in the assets folder. I would like to store them on firebase storage to call them when needed. Is it possible ? And how ? Thank you

For exemple I have a file upload on firebase storage with the name : `image1.jpg`

instead of

```
new Image.asset(
      "assets/image1.jpg",
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ).image,
```

I search to have something like

```
 -> download locally "image1.jpg" from firebase storage
 -> display  new Image.asset(
          "path of dowloaded image1.jpg from local folder",
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        ).image,
 -> remove image1.jpg after close page
```

Comment: Yes You can do it.Once you upload these files you will get downloadUrl which you can use in your app.

Comment: Ideally you'll want the images to be on something like an S3, but firebase storage would work just fine.

Once you get the URL from the firebae SDK you can use something like - https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/cached-images to display the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `downloadableURL` for the image and use it in app just like @Rohit mentioned in the comment.

```
printUrl() async { 
     StorageReference ref = 
         FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images/sky.jpg"); 
     String url = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString(); 
     print(url); 
}
```

You can go through this documentations for Upload files with Cloud Storage on Flutter https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files